# Exchanging values of two column of two different tables

Tags: mysql, database, join

to everybody! I am new to PHP and MYSQL

My question:
I have created a search box`

```
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />

<label>Search Category:
<select name="category">
<option value="registration">Registration no</option>
 </select>
</label>

<label>Search: <input type="text" name="criteria" /></label>
<input type="submit"/>`
```

I have a database student with two tables **student_info** and **levels**. The **student_info** table contains `name` (varchar), `level` (int). The **levels** table holds `levelid` and `levelName` columns. The `levelid` column holds record number (1,2,3..) and 
`levelName` contains BBA,BCA,MBA records etc.
From the table **student_info**, `level` column holds values 1,2,3 ...

Problem: 
When a user puts his registration number, then the data is fetched from **student_info** table.

So `level` shows the integer value. I want `level` of the **student_info** table to get the value of `levelName` column.

I have done this `$query = "SELECT * FROM student_info WHERE $category = '$criteria';";`
to get the searched result. The searched result shows level column values of the student_info  table and it's either 1 or 2 or .....

I want a query to exchange values between level column of student_info table and levelName of the levels table.

Please give a clear demonstration. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to retrieve additional information from a related table, you have to perform a JOIN.

Try:

```
SELECT s.name, l.levelName
FROM student_info s
INNER JOIN levels l ON s.level = l.levelid
WHERE <insert whatever conditional here>
```

You can learn more about joins by going to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)